# Count the whistles

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Sports Teacher gathered all the players in his garden and ordered them to line up. After the whistle all players should change the order in which they stand.

Teacher gave all the students numbers from 1 to N. For each place i he determined the unique position j. After whistling the player staying on position i should run to the j-th position. Teacher loved seeing how the players move around, and he continued whistling until the evening. He finished the game only when he noticed that the players are in the same order in which they were standing originally.

Now the teacher asks the question: How many times has he whistled?

Example : Let Their are 5 students initially in this order : 2 3 1 5 4

Then here answer will be 6 as after 6 moves all players will be back in initial position

Explanation : Here are 6 moves :

```
1. 3 1 2 5 4
2. 2 3 1 4 5
3. 1 2 3 5 4
4. 3 1 2 4 5
5. 2 3 1 5 4
6. 1 2 3 4 5
```

Here 1 ≤ N ≤ 100000

All A[i] are distinct numbers from 1 to N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $N$ students lets say $N1$ positions have their values within these $N1$ numbers and the rest $N2$  $(where N1+N2= N)$ positions also have their values within this $N2$ numbers.  In any given set of such $K$ values, the positions repeat their values after $K$ movements. This is because each position is assigned a different value, and each number has to pass through each of these K positions before coming back to its original poistion. So, N1 comes back to original postion after $N1$ iterations and $N2$ after $N2$ iteration. Both of them together come in original position after time $LCM(N1,N2)$.

In the given example 1,2,3 is one such set of count 3 and 4,5 is another set of count 2. The nu ber of iteration is the $LCM(2,3) = 6$ . If there are K such disjoint set such that the K sets have cardinality $N1,N2....Nk$. Then the number of movements is $LCM(N1,N2...Nk)$

edit1:
consider your example.Here $K=2$, they are {1,2,3} and {4,5}. To be more specific, find the mappings where $range = domain$. Now take the set 1,2,3.. this set is assinged the values 2,3,1. Since each of these values are different and there are total 3 values. Starting from 1 point it takes 3 movements to reach the same point. On each move you will move to a new position and that new position will have a new value. All the choices will be exhausted after 3 moves. Similarly the group 4,5. So basically you break up your problem into disjoint problems and find the case when they all come to original position, which is the LCM of their cardinality

edit2: You can find the disjoint subsets in N iterations. Start at any position, traverse through the positions as per the assigned order. Since each position is different, if you reach the same node you started with after $N1$ steps, you would have traversed $N1$  different positions and you can remove these positions. Now start at the any of the remaining position and repeat the process. Each time you reach the same position again in $Ni$ steps, you can remove $Ni$ positions. So finally the total number of iterations will be equal to the number of positions

Comment: Please explain a bit more.Am not getting it

Comment: How to find this K?Am not getting this.Indirectly how to find N1,N2,N3...NK

Comment: @user157452   I have edited my answer.

Comment: How are you finding these disjoint problems?

Comment: @user157452    you have to choose a position, then move to the next position  and so on, till you reach the same position. This will give you the 1st set. Now remove all these positions. Start from any other remaining position and repeat the process till you have traveresed each and every position

Comment: WHat about finding connected components in this question.?

Comment: @user157452  I dont think there is any direct equation as such to find the subsets. You have to traverse through the positions to separate each subsets

Comment: But how?I thought about it But cant come to any efficeint algorithm

Comment: @user157452        even I couldn't get an efficient algorithm. In the best and worst case, you can partition the set in N iteration

Comment: You mean partitioning can be done in O(N) ?

Comment: @user157452   exactly N!!   you need to traverse each position only once.

Comment: How?PLease edit it in your answer

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there was a loop of three numbers - (3,1,2), and a loop of two numbers (4,5).  The first loop returns to the initial position every three moves, and the second loop returns every two moves.  So to finish, you need a number of moves that is a multiple of both 2 and 3 - that is, six.

If you had a loop of 4 and a loop of 6, they would return to the start after 12 moves - not 4x6, but the lowest common multiple of 4 and 6.

One way to get a large common multiple is to choose loops of every prime order - one of 2, one of 3, one of 5, 7 and so on.  Keep going until you run out of students.  The number of moves needed would then be the product of those primes.

Comment: How are you finding these loops??

Comment: Just look at one of the students - say, Student 1.  After one move, they are in position 3.  After the next move, they are in position 2, and then to position 1.  So positions 1,3,2 form a loop.  Students 2 and 3 go through the same loop.  Now look at a student that has not been counted yet - Student 4.